# How can I "meteor run android-device" to my meteor server?

Tags: android, meteor

If I use the command:

```
meteor run android-device -p 192.168.232.142:3000
```

I have the following error:

```
Can't listen on host 192.168.232.142 (EADDRNOTAVAIL from listen).
```

That's logic, as the 192.168.232.142 is not my local IP address, but the IP address of my remote Meteor development server.
On the other hand, the same command on my remote Meteor dev server will not be helpful as I cannot attach my Android device to it. (With USB a adb).

So, how can I, install an android web app on my locally connected Android device pointing to a remote Meteor server?

Thanks,

Comment: +1, would like to know this too.

Answer (score 3):

This command works just fine:

```
meteor run android-device --mobile-server http://remote_server.meteor.com
```